# Dividing one column into two, then joining new columns with other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB with three tables.

1. "Campaign" table has a column "Campaign number" (e.g. value = `1`)
2. "Payment" table has a column "user_id" (e.g. value = `134356`)
3. "User_Source" table has a column "dump" which contains **both the user id and campaign number**: `info_u134356_cpn_1` OR `info_cpn_1_u134356`

I need to divide the data from the combined values in user_source, so that I would be able to see user_id and their linked campaign number in one table, and then count how many users are attributed to each campaign.

I can't get my head around the way to split ths column, and whether there is a way to do s without spitting (e.g. somehow filtering).

I'm currently using DataGrip for this.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or SQLite...they are very different databases (for your sake, I hope it's Postgres).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I started out with SQLite because that was the format this was all in, but I was pretty uncomfortable with it at this point (I've only played around in Postgres before). Now I've actually gotten all of this into DataGrip. Thanks for pointing that out, I should've mentioned it!

Comment: Take a look at the Horse's Postgres answer, if that would work for you.

Comment: The SQL client you use (DataGrip) is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name got it, thanks, it's my first time posting here and I'm not sure what is/isn't relevant :) Thanks for the regex solution! I'm wondering whether there's a way to do this in sqlite though? Or what would be a valid workaround?

Comment: No Idea. I don't use SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_match()` in Postgres:

```
with sample (dump) as (
   values 
    ('info_cpn_1_u134356'),
    ('info_u456789_cpn_5')
)
select (regexp_match(dump, 'u([0-9]+)'))[1] as user_id, 
       (regexp_match(dump, 'cpn_([0-9]+)'))[1] as campaign
from sample;
```

returns:

```
user_id | campaign
--------+---------
134356  | 1       
456789  | 5
```